# Cancelling scheduled chkdisk on Win7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I cancel CHKDSK in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/365231/how-can-i-cancel-chkdsk-in-windows-7)

I suspected some problems with my harddrive yesterday, so I scheduled a chkdisk via the Tool tab on the two partitions affected (I scheduled chkdisk on both partitions). Unfortunately, I did not know about the long processing time the program would have on a 1 TB drive so now I am not particularly eager to boot it up.

I did not tick the second type of scan ("Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors"), but can I somehow disable the scan? The computer is shut down for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you press F8 when it is booting up, you will be taken to an Advanced Options screen.

Here if you choose `Last Known Good Configuration`, it should skip check disk.

Comment: That sounds promising! Is there also a time-based prompt before the chkdisk begins or will it begin instantly if I miss the F8? If I miss the F8, should I do a hard reboot and try again?

Comment: I think by default, there is a 30 second period before it will boot normally, which will trigger the chkdsk. If you do miss it, from what I have read, it is definitely not recommended to reboot until it reaches stage 4 or 5, if you reboot when it is on stage 1,2 or 3, the chance of data loss is quite high.